# FInding difficulty in updating a doc in MERN stack React Native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, frontend

I don't know where II am missing something in the code as It's working clearly from postman.

my backend Nodejs server function is :

```
exports.updateFCMToken = (req, res) => {
    try {
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            {
                $set: {
                    fcmToken: req.body.fcmToken
                }
            },
            (err, doc) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(400).send('update FCMToken - Error')
                }
                return res.status(200).send('FCMToken Updated Successfully')
            }
        )
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send('server Error - FCMToken')
    }
}
```

From component I am calling the action:

```
useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            dispatch(updateFCMTokenAction());
        }, 1000);
    }, [])
```

my action.js: (doc id and fcmtoken are not similar to output shown in code)

```
export const updateFCMTokenAction = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            dispatch({ type: userConstants.UPDATE_FCMTOKEN_REQUEST });
            getToken();
            const fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
            const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
            const pushToken = {fcmToken};
            const id = JSON.parse(user)._id; // output: 63806e0f4dzeb09a2c03f731
            console.log('-----------------updateFCMTokenAction--------------');
            console.log('updateFCMTokenAction-fcmToken:', pushToken); // output: {"fcmToken": "fv4-4GIWTymgrt7e3klaPs:APA91bGXOLTNfp4-j4dPVDEL-6lDVUA7GWZchwx4j2BlVPOvOsq3pDOk06xkfBE-Q-J6Q4zix8LX-Jf-69Ey2T22aYmbiVD4j4_kMbVlZa8ip1MRtQ-ZDs0hMpno53o7BjmB9Opc-LWR"}
            const res = await axiosInstance.post(`/updatefcmtoken/${id}`, pushToken);            
            console.log('res: ', res);
            dispatch({ type: userConstants.UPDATE_FCMTOKEN_SUCCESS, payload: res.data });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('push-err: ', err)
            dispatch({ type: userConstants.UPDATE_FCMTOKEN_FAILURE, payload: err });
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error as :

```
push-err:  [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400]
```

What am I missing/unable to see here ?
Thank You ,

Comment: Your `try...catch` doesn't do anything because you are using a callback instead of a promise

Comment: There should be more detailed error in the terminal

Comment: @Konrad, Thank you for reply , may you correct me on how to do with promise in catch ().
Thanks